# Finding fmin using a Python lambda function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lambda

I have been trying to find the min of this function but i cant seem to get the proper syntax. y2 and y1a are numpy arrays im trying to pass to my lambda function and x is my third variable used by fmin.

```
        y2 = numpy.array(Apple[i:i+len(Leal)])
        y1 = Leal

        y1a = y1 + dif

        y = lambda x, y2, y1a: sum(abs((y2)+x)-y1a)
        emin = fmin(y,0)
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what function you're trying to get the minimum of.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: y2 and y1a are arrays, i would like to find at what value of x added to array y2 would cause y2-y1a to have the least difference. In a nute shell what im trying to do is to minimize the error between the two. I would like to then record the value of x that would create the smallest y

Comment: What happens if you try `y = lambda x:sum(abs(y2+x)-y1a`?

Comment: eclipse tells me that y2 and y1a are undefined variables if i do not state them with x

Comment: I don't know anything about eclipse, but they should get picked up via closure if this is really a portion of your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Your y function takes 3 values, but fmin supplies only one...

You need to either supply an array as initial estimate or, the other arguments as `args`

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html

assuming you need the latter:

```
fmin(y, 0, args=(y2, y1a))
```

Comment: y2 = numpy.array(Apple[i:i+len(Leal)])
            y1a = y1 + dif
         
            y = lambda x, y2, y1a: sum(abs((y2)+x)-y1a)
            emin = fmin(y,0,args=(y2, y1a))    I tried passing the arrays as you stated and it still will not work, do you think it is because I am trying to pass numpy arrays?

Comment: that's the same thing you wrote in the question, and it's definitely not enough for me to reproduce: what is `Apple`? what is `Leal`? (also, you forgot the `;` to separate the statements)... I tested your code by defining `Leal = numpy.array(range(10000)` `Apple = list(range(10000))` `y1a=y1` and it works